# Magento 1.8 only some CMS pages 302 redirects to home page

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, content-management-system

I've got a problem with my Magento CMS pages. On my homepage I've got footer links that bring the customer to CMS pages with success when they're clicked.

I tried to add 2 more links with their own CMS pages and impossible to access them.
The working links look like this:

```
<li class="uppercase"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('qui-sommes-nous') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Who are we ?') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Who are we ?') ?></a></li>
```

Then, for the same code with the correct link it redirects my link to the homepage with a 302 code.

I went to a redirect checker website and it said that I had 302 redirects on the homepage when I click only on my new links only.

I already did the following:
Go to my admin panel to uncheck Redirect to Base Url;

Go to {MagentoRootFolder}/app/etc/modules and remove modules one by one to see if there is a module that creates the issue.

Look in my .htaccess to comment Redirect directives.

I don't find the origin of this redirection if someone could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

It came from the fact that previous developers blacklisted all CMS pages in a Module Observer but the ones on the homepage (the ones which works) so I added my CMS pages to the whitelist and it works fine now.

```
if (Mage::getStoreConfig('privatesales/forcelogin/enable')) {

        $requestPathWhiteList = array(

            '[Path you want to whitelist]',
            '[Path you want to whitelist]',
            '[Path you want to whitelist]',
            '[Path you want to whitelist]',
            '[Path you want to whitelist]',
        );

        $cmsPageIdentifierWhiteList = array(
            '[URL KEY of your cms page you want to whitelist]',
            '[URL KEY of your cms page you want to whitelist]',
            '[URL KEY of your cms page you want to whitelist]',
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change CMS page URL key and then try. You can also check it in URL Rewrite section. Is there any rules define for these CMS page or not.

Comment: I tried these but I'm still having the issue. I don't understand why actual link to CMS pages work and since I want to replace them by a new one I created it redirects me to my homepage.